# decrease the opacity of the form without changing other components

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to make the form transparent, but only the form without the text or buttons placed on the form

I used the property "`AlphaBlend`" and put the value `150`

I want to leave like this print screen

[image]

Comment: But in that screen, the text and controls are not opaque. The screen behind them shows through behind the list box, the button, and the text. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I would take the screenshot of what's behind, draw it on the maximized form and semi-transparently fill the area with the blue color. That would *freeze* the screen which is in my view better for filling some information (than some living banner on behind for instance).

Comment: "to resume using your computer normally make a payment by calling..." Malware, huh?

Comment: @OnTheFly, ...or press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to start cleaning up your computer :-) Maybe it's just some sort of public kiosk with a very weird and suspicious payment type...

Comment: @TLama, nah, such trojans will disable/replace Task Manager. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware_%28malware%29)

Comment: I naturally get the sense of malware too. Perhaps that's why OP didn't want to convert it to English?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Delphi and Windows version, you can achieve this by setting the Form properties `DoubleBuffered` = true and `GlassFrame.Enabled = true` and `GlassFrame.SheetOfGlass = true.`

Comment: I'm using Delphi 7, does not have these options

Comment: +1 To Uwe, and -1 for offboard. Adding constraints after the question has been answered is bad form.

Comment: +1 If OP had originally restricted the question to Delphi 7, then I'm sure this answer wouldn't be here. But since no version was mentioned, solutions from any version are theoretically correct answers.